# How can I implement a tag cloud on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, tag-cloud

like this one here:

[image]

Is there an existing class that I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some of the string drawing methods to find out how large a frame you need for each tag, and then size a bunch of UILabels to fit each word.

As you'll likely want your user to interact with the tags, subclass UILabel to handle touches where appropriate.