# iphone word map

Tags: iphone

How can I make a word map application on iPhone like the one shown in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2hCf5FPCSc)?
I dont think that there is any built in widget for the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this question [How can I implement a tag cloud on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408221/how-can-i-implement-a-tag-cloud-on-iphone)